# SQLite3 memory error when reading from a large database (> 1GB)

Tags: python, eclipse, memory, sqlite

I have a small Python 2.7 script that uses LIKE statements to extract pieces of information from textual data stored in a SQLite database.

```
sql = "SELECT user_id, loc,\
        FROM entity\
        WHERE loc LIKE '%\"place\":%'\
        AND loc LIKE '%\"geo\":%'\
    AND loc LIKE '%\"coordinates\":%'" 
cin.execute(sql)
entities = cin.fetchall()
```

`cin` is a cursor to a SQLite database (table `entity` with >10^6 rows) (~1.5GB) which was established using

```
import sqlite3
try:
    dbin = sqlite3.connect(database=args['dbi'].name)
    dbin.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cin = dbin.cursor()
except sqlite3.Error, e:
    errorLogger.error('... %e' % e)
    sys.exit()
```

The script ran fine with database sizes of 10^2 MB, but now I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\migrate.py", line 247, in <module>
    entities = cin.fetchall()
MemoryError
```

after some seconds. *I am running a W7 64bit machine with 8GB RAM*.  When the script is running, by looking at the resources monitor of W7, I can tell that successively all free memory is used and python.exe consumes as much as 1.9GB just before the program crashes. Still, there is about 3GB standby memory available (but don't ask me what's the difference between standby and free memory).

What can I do about this besides pre-filtering my query, e.g. by only looking at, let's say, 10'000 rows per query?

Comment: Why not use `'''` triple-quotes instead of all those backslashes?

Comment: Do you really need to call `fetchall()`? Looks like you have too many results, you can iterate over the cursor and process the rows one by one instead of loading it all into memory.

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit or a 64-bit Python?

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 for the hint with the triple-quotes, didn't know about them, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `fetchall` requires allocating memory for all result records.

You should instead read the result records from `cin` one by one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint, I thought all the fetching would happen within the `execute` function, thus using `fetchone` or `fetchall` wouldn't matter, but you proved me wrong. Works like a charm.